# Visual Studio default location issue, when loading external files

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When trying to load a file from a target project directory using in C#

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

Visual Studio keeps looking for the file in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\
```

The problem is that an annoying error about it keeps appearing, although the application builds, compiles and runs without issues, since the file exists in the project target directory.

Does anybody have any idea or previous experience?

Comment: *"when loading external files"* - can you show relevant source code?

Comment: Maybe `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` or `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` can help?

Comment: What I am using is

var file_path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "file.txt");

Comment: There is absolutely no problem in finding and processing the file with the way I do. The only problem is that Visual Studio keeps showing an error, saying that the required external file doesn't exist in the directory I mention in the question...

Comment: @HansPassant I would accept the value of your reputation number, if you could actually try to help, rather than make fun of a person's question...

Comment: What's the exact error VS is throwing at you?

Comment: `Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\text.txt'`

Comment: @swdon I just want to say again, that the program runs fine. It is just that error VS keeps giving, that I want to get rid of...

Comment: Your code is not searching for "text.txt" right? It's looking for "file.txt". So the code you posted and this error aren't related. There's some other code somewhere asking for a "text.txt". But it's a bit confusing when you say your application runs fine but VS gives this error. Perhaps, take a screenshot of where you are getting this error and post.

Comment: Right! The txt files have the same name. It was a typo, that I cannot edit and correct.
It is very confusing indeed! That's why I thought someone in this community had experience of something similar, and I asked...

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Ru5igCE

Comment: I understand that the first (and probably only) thing that comes to mind is that the file doesn't exist in the bin/Debug directory, but trust me, it **does** exist and the program **does** run normally. That error appears, when and only I exit the application. When I build or start the application, it error disappears!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the error -> Show error help, got me to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/xaml-errors-warnings?view=vs-2017) page, and by doing this, the error disappeared. I am yet to understand, how that had anything to do with the  xaml designer.